# jsf 2.2.x AjaxBehaviorEvent listener no refresh multipart/form-data

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, listener

I have a

```
<h:form prependid="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
  <h:inputText value="#{mybean.someStringField}" />
  <h:inputFile id="myFile" value="#{mybean.somePartField}" /> 
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{mybean.someField}" >   
    <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.someSelectItemList}" >
    <f:ajax event="change" execute="@form" render="@form" immediate="true" listener="#{mybean.someListenerAjaxBehaviorEvent}" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>  
</h:form>
```

when change value on selectOneMenu this form no refresh form

the method someListenerAjaxBehaviorEvent consists of a code like the following

```
public void someListenerAjaxBehaviorEvent(AjaxBehaviorEvent ev) throws AbortProcessingException {
  try
  {
    String code = (String)((UIOutput)ev.getSource()).getValue();
    ...
    // Some SQL sentences for update data list
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

This method works correctly when the form is not of type "multipart/form-data" but I need to attach some files on this form.
Anyone have any ideas that can help me solve the problem, I greatly appreciate their contributions

Comment: Multipart forms seem notoriously buggy. What happens when you fire that event? Is a request generated at all? Is your listener called?

Comment: Nothing happens, the listener does not fire, I add a message to console the listener "System.out.println (" message ")", but not shown

Comment: I still have not solved this problem, could someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Sory, i can't add comment.

You should use `</h:form>` instead of `</form>` to close to form.
Did you try add some log to method someListenerAjaxBehaviorEvent to check if it was invoke?

Comment: "sorry, I'm wrong on the issue in question, but in my code is the end tag </ h: form>"

Comment: Which JSF version do you use? JSF 2.2.x had a bug in early versions. Try the newest version.

Comment: currently use JSF 2.2.6 but I've also tested with 2.2.2 and 2.2.3 but with any version it worked